# richTextArea.setHTML() function calling throgh anchor tag

Tags: gwt

`richTextArea.setHTML("<a href='#' onClick= MyFunc();>"+"Visit W3Schools.com!"+"</a>");`

Call the java script function....

```
 private native void  MyFunc() /*-{
          alert("dhd");
          }-*/;
```

fun its not working

Comment: Why are you using a RichText box to show an HTML link? GWT is perfectly capable of creating Anchors and doing every bit of styling you could possibly do with a RichText box and a whole lot more...

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you have to use the reference to the object where you want to call the `MyFunc()`!!!

so look at the GWT-SIte, there is described how to access the Functions!